# How to add conditions for blank prompts in PSQuery?

Tags: sql, oracle, peoplesoft

I need help with myPS Query. This is how it goes below:

```
 SELECT A.EMPLID, B.STUDENT_ID, C.ADMIT_TERM, D.CHECKLIST_CD, 
 D.CHECKLIST_STATUS...
 FROM TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B, TABLE3C, TABLE4 D...
 WHERE……
 AND A.EMPLID = :1
 AND C.ADMIT_TERM = :2
 AND D.CHECKLIST_CD = :3
 AND D.CHECKLIST_STATUS = :4
 ….
```

Now there are certain conditions wherein prompts 1,2,3 and 4 are not provided that conditions below should happen:

- All students with incomplete / in progress checklists will be shown regardless of when they were created.
- All students whose checklists were completed within the current Term will be shown.

At this point, I don't know how to add a condition if all those prompts are blank. Can you advise what I need to do next? Sub-queries? Expression?

Help please.

Comment: This kinda depends on more specifics about your requirements.  And also how much you know PS/Query.  One approach however would be **not** to try to everything in PS/Query and instead pre-chew some of the work with a standard Oracle view that you would create and could then run your Query against.  You can't really express a bind variable in a View though so the specific details of what you are trying to do matter.

Comment: Are you doing this through the query designer or typing the SQL yourself?

Comment: @BenRubin: I can do both as long as it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically the same as Littlefoot's answer, but I'll try to add some more detail about how to accomplish that solution.  This is an example of a query I did which is similar to what you're trying to do, with a little tweak added on the `ORDER_NO` field to demonstrate what you're trying to do.  I don't know how to make it return certain rows only if *all* prompts are not provided, but this will let you return certain rows for each specific prompt which isn't provided.  For example, if you don't provide a checklist status, then you can return all students that are in incomplete and in progress status.

Note that this is a very old version of PeopleSoft, so your interface is probably different.

First, add your prompts

[image]

Now, the trick is to make the `WHERE` clause for each optional field work like `WHERE (D.CHECKLIST_STATUS = :4 OR (:4 = '' AND D.CHECKLIST_STATUS IN ('I', 'P'))` (or whatever your status codes are).  Here's how to do that (again, on my old version).  The logic on the `ORDER_NO` field is similar to what you'll need.

[image]

*Make sure to set your `AND/OR` operators and your parenthesis appropriately.*

[image]

Clicking on the Edit button for the `'' equal to :2` criteria, this is what it looks like

[image]

And the SQL looks like this

[image]

Now when you run the query, any of the prompt fields that you leave empty will either not be used to filter the results, or the default values for that field will be used.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, it is usually handled as follows:

```
select ...
from ...
where (a.emplid      = :1 or :1 is null)
  and (c.admint_term = :2 or :2 is null)
  ...
```

Comment: how do I add the condition from there? When given that they are not provided or 'null', should there be a 'then statement', where do i put it?

Comment: I don't know Peoplesoft; as I said, in Oracle you deal with such things as I explained - enclose condition into brackets (because of OR) and ... write what I wrote. No `then` at all, it is SQL, not PL/SQL. If it doesn't work in Peoplesoft, sorry - I wouldn't know what to do.

Comment: Not very helpful.  PeopleSoft specifically forbids NULLs on anything but Date/DateTime fields so a condition that looks for them on a Charfield like EMPLID is useless.

Comment: @JLPeyret, is there anything you can suggest so that Link solves the problem? I, unfortunately & obviously, can't ...

Comment: @Littlefoot.  No offense meant in my remark, but yes, NULLs & PeopleSoft are, by design, somewhat mutually exclusive which is why I mentioned it before the OP spent time investigating.

Comment: @JLP, in mine neither; I was just hoping that you might know what to do; though, the opposite (i.e. what *not* to do) is also a time-savior :)

Answer (score 0):

Use **LIKE** instead of **=** operator. For instance

SELECT A.EMPLID, B.STUDENT_ID
 FROM TABLE1 A
 WHERE
 AND A.EMPLID LIKE :1

if you want to select all the employees then pass % in :1 parameter.

Comment: Interestingly, I created something like that that actually works. see below:

1 AND A.EMPLID LIKE DECODE (:1, ' ', '%', :1) 

My problem now is what if one of the prompts has a value and only those blank values is where i pass the '%'. Can it be like the one below where i pass '%' to a field or it has to be a prompt.

2 = 2 AND CASE 
WHEN :2 = ' ' AND :3 = ' ' AND :4 = ' ' AND :5 = ' ' THEN
 A.ADM_APPL_NBR = '%' AND
 C.CHECKLIST_CD = '%' AND
 C.CHEKLIST_STATUS = '%' AND

Comment: Fieldname Like '%' works in all conditions except when fieldvalue is NULL. And PeopleSoft has field value NULL only for field data type Date. For all other data types it keeps '' instead of NULL